# Перенос истории коммитов в другой репозиторий

Tags: git

Как будет проще все коммиты из локального гит-репозитория перенести уже в совершенно другой репозиторий?

Иными словами накодил я целую историю коммитов по одному файлу, и тут захотел добавить этот файл в другой репозиторий, но с историей коммитов по нему.

Comment: см. ответы на [более глобальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/551847/178576)

Answer (score 3):

Вот уже сам нашёл решение :

```
git remote add repo_b /путь/к/папке/с/локальным/репозиторием/...

git pull repo_b master
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше ответ не работает. Если вы используете вебшторм все что вам нужно сделать, это ремоут ветку и просто коммитить изменения туда. В результате этого, вся история проекта сохраниться без изменений