# переместить файлы из одного репозитория в другой с историей коммитов

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Здравствуйте. У меня есть два репозитория

Checker.rep

- 1Ch.file
- 2Ch.file
- 3Ch.file

Main.rep

- Checker.folder

Подскажите как переместить файлы из репозитория Checker.rep в папку Checker.folder так, чтобы история коммитов сохранилась и можно было удалить оставшийся пустой репозиторий Checker?

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262794/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9?rq=1).

Comment: @СашаЧерных если следовать приведённым там инструкциям, три означенных файла окажутся **в корне** этого репозитория, а не в папке внутри него. Конечно, их можно отдельным коммитом перенести... Но это плохой стиль. Каждый коммит должен быть самодостаточным.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку это две отдельных несвязанных истории, чтобы их связать, придётся делать **слияние**. Сбивает с толку тот факт, что ветки в разных репозиториях, и как слияние делать, неясно... [это поправимо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/262794/181100), хотя и не совсем так, как по ссылке. **Один репозиторий можно затянуть в другой.**

Просто делать `pull` из другого репозитория не стоит, потому что в этом случае файлы из корня одного репозитория попадут в корень другого, а цель немножко другая. Поэтому вместо `pull` сделаем то, из чего он состоит: `fetch`+`merge`.

В `Main.rep`

```
git remote add checker путь/к/Checker.rep # указать источник
git fetch checker                         # только скачать (!) коммиты
# warning: no common commits              # <- ну, это ожидаемо
# remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
# remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
# remote: Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
# Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
# From путь/к/Checker.rep
#  * [new branch]      master     -> checker/master
git merge checker/master --no-commit
```

Интерес представляет флаг `--no-commit` (ради этого и затевался обход вокруг `pull`), который после завершения процедуры слияния **остановит Git**, чтобы можно было поправить результаты. Самое время закинуть прилетевшие при слиянии файлы в нужную папку:

```
git mv *Ch.file Checker.folder
```

Вот вроде и всё, достигнуто желаемое состояние.

```
git commit
```

Готово.