# Вынести модуль в отдельный репозиторий с сохранением истории коммитов

Tags: git, gitlab

Есть монорепозиторный проект с несколькими модулями. Возникла необходимость вынести модули в отдельные репозитории. Возможно ли это сделать с сохранением истории коммитов и авторов?

На первый взгляд вариант с fork-ом всего проекта и с последующим изменением деталей более подходящий, мешает лишь сама идея fork-а, и в дальнейшем проект-предок будет удален.

Текущая система хранения репозиториев GitLab

Comment: `мешает лишь сама идея fork-а` - чем мешает?

Comment: Мне не нужна возможность трэкать вышестоящий проект, не нужны возможности синхронизации. Нашел вариант с 'git remote add' подходящим

Comment: `Нашел вариант с 'git remote add' подходящим` - эээ... Это добавление ссылки на еще одну репу. Он ничего не делает кроме этого. Не понятно, как им можно разрулить ситуацию с выносом в отдельные репы. Или вы используете submodules?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514870/258242  тут решение аналогичной проблемы. Извиняюсь за дубликат, сразу не нашел

Comment: конечно же после клонирования дополнительно придется удалить ссылку на remote `git remote rm source_repo`, иначе ваш проект продолжит трэкать исходник

Answer (score 1):

`git subtree ...` должна помочь: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-man/git-subtree.1.en.html

Полный скрипт который это делает тут:
https://gitlab.com/softmill/git/helpers/-/blob/master/git_extract_dir_to_another_repo.sh