# Как создать git-репозиторий на базе репозитория подрядчика

Tags: git

Кратко задача звучит следующим образом: как создать репозиторий на базе репозитория подрядчика, если планируется дальнейшая совместная работа над проектом?

Ниже -- детали вопроса.

Организация-заказчик. В интернет выставлен сервер, используемый в качестве git-сервера, сложных методологий работы с git (типа `git-flow`) не использовали - хватало модели «общего репозитория» (The Shared Repository Model). Одна ветка `master`, в которую вливали все изменения - вот и вся методика.

Организация-подрядчик. В интернет выставлен сервер с `gitlab` на борту. Можно сделать `git clone` на "посмотреть".

Вопрос заключается в том, как быть, когда разработка завершится и придёт пора передавать артефакты проекта и подымать проект уже на собственных серверах.

Хочется следующего:

- забрать проект полностью на свой сервер и работать с ним уже у себя
- сохранить всю историю ведения проекта подрядчиком, а не начинать репозиторий с нуля
- иметь возможность синхронизировать репозитории: чтобы подрядчики могли забрать текущие доработки с нашего гит, чтобы мы могли забрать отдельные патчи с их сервера.

Comment: постарайтесь, пожалуйста, сократить вопрос, оставив только ключевую информацию. чтобы вопрос и ответы на него могли быть полезны не только вам.

Comment: Итого, вдумчиво прочитал всё, потестировал. Затрудняюсь даже кому поставить галку, обоих авторов постоянно вижу с толковыми ответами на stackoverflow и по моему вопросу тоже оба мне помогли в равной мере. У KoVadim хорошо прописаны схемы работы с плюсами-минусами, это был полезный обзор и отсылка к модели "рабочий процесс с менеджерами по интеграции" (из которого правда я не почерпнул никаких подробностей, как именно это делается). У Александра больше конструктор "собери себе сам подходящее" и очень полезные ссылки на конкретику, именно они довели общий концепт до конкретного прототипа.

Comment: Ниже добавляю свой ответ: по сути это всё то же самое, просто намного подробнее. Возможно, кому-либо ещё пригодится.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В любом случае, кто то должен кому то дать доступ к репозиторию. Но гит на то он и гит, что позволяет использовать два удаленных репозитория.

**Первый вариант**. Назначается один (или несколько) "ответственный за интеграцию". У него должен быть доступ к обеим серверам с гит репозитариями. Он будет пулить с обеих репозиториев, мерджить и пушить обратно. Детальнее можно читать [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B). Если админы и начальство категорически не разрешает выпускать гит наружу (всякое бывает), то данный человек может делать это с ноутбуком и перемещатся между офисами или использовать vpn.

Если изменения будут проходить в основном с одной стороны, то работа будет очень простой.

**Плюсы**:

- репозитории легко поддерживать в согласованном состоянии
- минимум ручной работы

**Минусы**:

- нужны доступы
- возможна утечка конфиденциальной информации

**Способ второй**. У каждого свой репозиторий. Когда вносят какие то изменения (пофиксили баг), то патч высылается почтой (обычной, электронной). А на другой строне просто применяется. В git для этого есть целый набор инструментов и достаточно хорошо [автоматизировано](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0). В этой схеме должно быть как минимум два человека - один, который будет формировать патчи и отправлять их почтой, другой, который будет их применять.

**Плюсы**:

- репозитории независимы.
- никто не знает, что именно есть в чужом репозитории.
- можно применять избранные патчи
- можно хорошо анализировать патчи

**Минусы**:

- репозитории скорее всего "разойдутся".
- много нужно делать "ручками"

Comment: Про второй способ когда-то [читал](https://habrahabr.ru/post/268951/), но рассматривать всерьёз не стал бы. Хотя -- даже не пришло в голову, что тоже так можно. Первый вариант любопытен, хотя я обдумывал ответы и уточнял детали вопроса - понял, что есть возможность выставить гит-сервера в интернет (один-то точно сумеем), а потому возможно получится придумать более удобную схему.

Comment: в любом случае, можно купить себе на github репозиторий и работать спокойно.

Answer (score 8):

Попробовал смоделировать ситуацию на двух тестовых репозиториях:

- avn - репозиторий, который находится у фирмы-подрядчика
- fcs - репозиторий, который находится у фирмы-заказчика

[image: Модель репозиториев]

Ответственных за интеграцию двое: один у заказчика, один у подрядчика.

Оба репозитория полагаем доступными по сети интернет для менеджеров.

---

Фаза 1. Разработка на сервере подрядчика.

Заполним два-три коммита для моделирования того, как подрядчик работает:

```
touch avn-file1.txt
git add avn-file1.txt
git commit -m "avn-file1.txt"
...
touch avn-file3.txt
git add avn-file3.txt
git commit -m "avn-file3.txt"
```

И периодически пушим их на сервер.

В какой-то момент принимается решение, что настал "час Х" и можно публиковать проект у заказчика. Останавливается разработка, в репозитории avn у подрядчика вот такая история коммитов:

```
pick fdf9508 avn-file1.txt
pick 0633d9c avn-file2.txt
pick 4d71f77 avn-file3.txt
```

Фаза 2. Создание собственного репозитория на базе репозитория подрядчика

Клонируем репозиторий подрядчика и переписываем origin на адрес собственного репозитория (правим файл `/.git/config` -- ну или по-грамотному: через `git remote set-url origin <сервер заказчика>`), затем `git push -f`.

Получаем на собственном сервере абсолютно точную копию репозитория подрядчика, с полным сохранением истории и даже SHA-1 коммитов будут совпадать:

```
pick fdf9508 avn-file1.txt
pick 0633d9c avn-file2.txt
pick 4d71f77 avn-file3.txt
```

Переходим к следующей фазе.

Фаза 3. Заказчик выполняет какие-то доработки на своё усмотрение и без оглядки на бывшего подрядчика.

Ну, допустим, опять же создадим несколько коммитов:

```
touch fcs-file1.txt
git add fcs-file1.txt
git commit -m "fcs-file1.txt"
...
touch fcs-file3.txt
git add fcs-file3.txt
git commit -m "fcs-file3.txt"
```

И будем их периодически пушить на собственный сервер. (В реальности fcs -- это bare-репозиторий на сервере, который несколько разрабочиков в компании-заказчика склонировали себе на рабочие станции, но это некритично для теста.)

Получаем на своём сервере такую историю:

```
pick fdf9508 avn-file1.txt
pick 0633d9c avn-file2.txt
pick 4d71f77 avn-file3.txt
pick 7dd4772 fcs-file1.txt
pick f33cdda fcs-file2.txt
pick c54c562 fcs-file3.txt
```

(Первые три коммита -- это сделанные когда-то подрядчиком, следующие три -- уже заказчик. У подрядчика до сих пор в его репозитории только три коммита)

И тут в некоторый момент, заказчик вспоминает про подрядчика и даёт ему какую-то задачу на доработку. Дальнейшее взаимодействие идёт по схеме: а) подрядчик забирает изменения сделанные заказчиком после сдачи проекта б) подрядчик делает какие-то доработки в своём репозитории в) заказчик забирает доработки к себе на сервер.

Итак, поехали:

Фаза 4. Подрядчик забирает изменения сделанные заказчиком

У подрядчика есть какой-то сотрудник, ответственный за интеграцию, скажем, Вася или Петя. Вася в репозитории avn (на своей машине) подключает удалённый репозиторий fcs и называет его (внезапно) именно как fcs:

```
git remote add fcs <адрес репозитория подрядчика>
```

И может периодически вливать в свою ветку мастер изменения, которые внесены заказчиком (разом, не мелочимся с fetch+merge):

```
[vasya@wrkst1 avn]$ git pull fcs master
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From gitserver:polygon/fcs
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 4d71f77..c54c562
Fast-forward
 fcs-file1.txt | 0
 fcs-file2.txt | 0
 fcs-file3.txt | 0
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 fcs-file1.txt
 create mode 100644 fcs-file2.txt
 create mode 100644 fcs-file3.txt
```

И на сервере подрядчика оказываются те же самые 6 коммитов, что и у заказчика с теми же самыми SHA-1.

Фаза 5. Подрядчик делает какую-то доработку

```
touch avn-megafix1.txt
git add avn-megafix1.txt
git commit -m "avn-megafix1.txt"
```

Теструет, заливает в своё хранилище, сообщает ответственному за интеграцию со стороны заказчика, чтобы тот забрал доработки.

Фаза 6. Заказчик забирает изменения в свой репозиторий.

В принципе, действия симметричны шагу 4: ответственный за интеграцию у заказчика подключает на своей копии репозитория fcs удалённый репозиторий avn:

```
git remote add avn <адрес репозитория подрядчика>
```

И после этого может забирать изменения с сервера подрядчика:

```
git pull avn master
```

Получая точно таки же коммиты, с теми же самыми идентификаторами SHA-1, что и у подрядчика.

В принципе, вот и всё в общих чертах. Действительно, ничего сложного - главное, чтобы сервера были доступны.

Comment: Некоторые моменты специфичны и я их не стал описывать, плюс работа с ветками фич не описана, в реально подразумевается создание локальных веток под фичи и мёрдж риквесты в удалённый гитлаб.

Answer (score 6):

> Вариант "передать бэкап базы и архив с файлами" разумеется не подходит: хочется оставить всю историю коммитов

*git* — это **распределённая** система управления версиями. любой клон (сделаный командой `git clone`) — это полноценное хранилище с полной историей. если единственный способ связи — обмен файлами, то можно воспользоваться, например, командой `git bundle`. или, в крайнем случае, сделать архив содержимого хранилища — то есть (в не-bare хранилище) каталога `.git`. в этом каталоге и содержится вся история.

> предусмотреть возможность внесения патчей подрядчиками

- без доступа к хранилищам друг друга заказчик и разработчик могут обмениваться патчами: с помощью команды `git format-patch` можно сформировать набор патчей (по одному на коммит), а с помощью команды `git apply` можно применить эти патчи к другому клону этого хранилища.
- если всё же есть доступ к хранилищу подрядчика по любому поддерживаемому программой *git* протоколу — *git/ssh/http/https*, то можно подключить к существующему клону и дополнительные хранилища с помощью команды `git remote`, забирать изменения командой `git fetch` и сливать их с локальной веткой командой `git merge`.

---

подробности:

- [создание пакетов (bundles)](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) и [`man git-bundle`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html)
- [патчи: общее применение](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch06.html#_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [`man git-format-patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html), [`man git-apply`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html)
- [несколько удалённых хранилищ](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch06.html#_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89) и [`man git-remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), [`man git-fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html), [`man git-merge`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, у нас в пятницу день самообразования -- постараюсь завтра и прочитать про по несколько удалённых хранилищ и погонять тесты.